# How to select a column with a number name in a table with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column named `0` in the table `mytable`. 
I want to select the contains of this column. when I tried with:

```
 SELECT 0 FROM mytable WHERE key_id =  '8'
```

It didn't show the column's data but it shows only the value 0 but this column doesn't have the 0 value.
How can I get the contents of this column?

Comment: Put tild (`) around 0 in SELECT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create table test_0(`0` INT );

INSERT INTO test_0 VALUES(1);

SELECT `0` FROM test_0;
+------+
| 0    |
+------+
|    1 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 3):

Since zero is a number you need to specify it with the `back ticks`

```
SELECT `0` FROM mytable WHERE key_id = '8'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
mysql_query("select * from `mytable` where `key_id`=8")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
create table test(`0` INT,key_id int );

INSERT INTO test VALUES(1,8);

SELECT `0` FROM test where key_id=8;
```

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2470d/2)